# Kernel access and stopping process before start

Tags: python, linux, process, linux-kernel

I want to catch processes in python before they started. I tried to catch them via listening processtree but it need too much CPU. How can I catch processes before they start. I'm trying to catch malware before they start. I want to interrupt when new process start and `SIGSTOP` it control then `SIGCONT`. Please give me some advice. Need to stop executable before it starts.Trying to make antivirus.

I tried auditing but its not useful because you cannot stop process before start.

Comment: You can create a wrapper. For example, if you want to catch `/usr/bin/app` rename it to `/usr/bin/app.orig` and do whatever you want in `/usr/bin/app` before actually running `/usr/bin/app.orig`

Comment: Ohhh i understand thats smart idea. But it should be like a tool and it shouldnt change anything. Can i force kernel to ask me before starting process?

Comment: You can create a utility that receives the executable to run as an argument, does your logic and then executes the desired binary.